# Load obj files and draw other figures inside a cube with size 1 - java opengl

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, opengl-3

I have to use JOGL to draw some figures and load objs from a file in order to implement some projections and rotations.

What I have now is a canvas with 4 viewports and inside of each is a teaPot, drawn with:

```
GLUT glu = new GLUT() ;
gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
glu.glutWireCube((float) 1.0); 
glu.glutWireTeapot((float) 1.0);
```

The cube that is in the code above is to give a perspective of what the size should the teapot have.

What I want and have to do is to scale the teapot to be always inside of the cube with size 1.

I have some idea to use scale and translate methods but I'm having some trouble. The scale is to make  the size of teapot and the translate to put the teapot in the center.

I don't know if I'm explaining the problem in the best way.

But the general idea is to load the object from the file directly to the center of a bounding box, and this bounding box is a cube with size 1.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Considering the lack of documentation of glutWireTeapot, how did you determine the bounding box of the teapot?

Answer (score 0):

At first, use JOGL 2. JOGL 1 is obsolete and unmaintained.

Secondly, there are several OBJ loaders in [jogl-utils](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl-utils/blob/master/src/net/java/joglutils/model/loader/WaveFrontLoader.java) and jogl-demos on Github but the most robust OBJ importer is in [JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation](https://github.com/gouessej/Ardor3D/), look in the sub-project "ardor3d-extras".